# Table of functions

Tags: functions, evaluation

Why does

```
Table[Function[{x}, x^m], {m, 1, 3}]
```

produce

```
{Function[{x}, x^m], Function[{x}, x^m], Function[{x}, x^m]}
```

(i.e. with `m` left not evaluated), and not

```
{Function[{x}, x^1], Function[{x}, x^2], Function[{x}, x^3]}
```

as I would have expected? How do I get the latter?

Comment: `Function[]` has the `HoldAll` attribute, so you'd need to do something like injection: `Table[With[{mt = m}, Function[{x}, x^mt]], {m, 1, 3}]`

Comment: you can also do `Table[Function @@ {{x}, x^m}, {m, 1, 3}]`

Comment: ..or `Table[Function[{x}, x^#] &@m, {m, 1, 3}]`

Comment: Or, `Function[{x}, x^#] & /@ Range[3]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it has to do with the fact that the Function symbol has the attribute "HoldAll" as can be seen by typing `Attributes[Function]`. According to the [documentation page for Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), this means "The function body is evaluated only after the formal parameters have been replaced by arguments" However, you're not passing the function parameters until after Table has run, and so it will hold the symbolic form of x^m. To get around this we can simply use a dummy variable "a" and symbolically replace it with m.

```
Table[Function[{x}, x^a] /. a -> m, {m, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around. However I do not quite understand still. Why does HoldAll not also prevent the ```a``` being replaced in your example?

Comment: @ComptonScattering See if this helps: `Table[{Function[{x}, x^a], Function[{x}, x^b]} /. a -> m, {m, 1, 3}]`. `a` is replaced after the table is created.

Answer (score 5):

Function has `HoldAll` attribute, but an arbitrary head `f` doesn't so:

```
Table[f[{x}, x^m], {m, 1, 3}] /. f -> Function
```

> {Function[{x}, x], Function[{x}, x^2], Function[{x}, x^3]}